# Why is `Array.isArray` behaving differently in TypeScript depending on how a variable is accessed?

Tags: typescript

I ran into this issue several times but didn't pay much attention. I was curious about why this is happening:

```
type ArgParam = { [parameter: string]: string | string[] }

function testFunc (parameters: ArgParam, params: string[]) {
    params.forEach((param) => {
        if (Array.isArray(parameters[param])) {
          const test = parameters[param]
         //     ^? -> type is `string | string[]` - Why? we just checked if its an array!!
        }
        if (Array.isArray(parameters['some string'])) {
          const test = parameters['some string']
         //     ^? -> type is `string[]` - this is expected!
        }
    })
}
```

See in [TypeScript playground](https://tsplay.dev/WKOKyW)

Comment: `param` is dynamic and may change between the condition and where you use it; `'some string'` is static and won't change, so TypeScript is able to "keep" the inference

Comment: Ok I get it now... I tried to clone the `params` variable and never changes it before the loop and the same behavior applies... I guess this is just the way it works currently

Comment: If you use another variable like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WJX15N), then it works.

Comment: Yeah this is what I was doing but I found it annoying to set extra variables when I knew the type would not change